# Flutter Radial Gauge Design using Syncfusion package

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I'm trying to implement a radial gauge just like the following design:
[image]

I have 4 problems
1- I can't add a border to a certain label
2- I can't position the gauge range label in the right place
3- I can't add an icon to the gauge range label
4- the needle pointer is not all in white.
The following code is the closest to the design:

```
 Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
          child: SfRadialGauge(
        axes: [
          RadialAxis(
            showLabels: true,
            showAxisLine: true, showLastLabel: false,
            axisLabelStyle: GaugeTextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            showTicks: false, maximumLabels: 3,
            startAngle: 180, labelFormat: "Entry {value}",
            endAngle: 0,
            minimum: 0,
            showFirstLabel: true,
            maximum: 10, interval: 5,
            ranges: [
              GaugeRange(
                startValue: 0,
                endValue: 5,
                color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                // label: 'hii',
                sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                endWidth: 1,
                startWidth: 1,
              ),
              GaugeRange(
                  startValue: 5,
                  endValue: 6,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  label: '1.975',
                  sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  startWidth: 1,
                  endWidth: 1),
              GaugeRange(
                  startValue: 6,
                  endValue: 7,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    label: '2.15',

                  sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  startWidth: 1,
                  endWidth: 1),
              GaugeRange(
                  startValue: 7,
                  endValue: 8,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    label: '2.557',
                  
                  sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  startWidth: 1,
                  endWidth: 1),
              GaugeRange(
                  startValue: 8,
                  endValue: 9,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  label: '3.555',
                  sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  startWidth: 1,
                  endWidth: 1),
              GaugeRange(
                  startValue: 9,
                  endValue: 10,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  label: '4.12',
                  sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  labelStyle: const GaugeTextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  startWidth: 1,
                  endWidth: 1),
            ],
            pointers: const <GaugePointer>[
              NeedlePointer(
                value: 4,
                enableAnimation: true,
                animationType: AnimationType.linear,
                needleColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
```

which produced the following design:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by using the annotations property in the SfRadialGauge.

Query 1: I can't add a border to a certain label:

By using the Container widget, you can add the border for the certain label using BoxDecoration widget in the decoration property.

Code snippet:

```
        annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
            GaugeAnnotation(
              axisValue: 0.5,
              positionFactor: 0.8,
              widget: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Stop 1.875',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Query 2:  I can't position the gauge range label in the right place.

By using the annotations property, you can place the gauge range label at the right place using axisValue property in the GaugeAnnotation.

Code snippet:

```
const GaugeAnnotation(
              axisValue: 9.5,
              positionFactor: 0.9,
              widget: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 60.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.ads_click,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
```

Query 3: I can't add an icon to the gauge range label.

By using the annotations, you can place the Icon by setting the widget property to Padding and axisValue in the GaugeAnnotation.

Code snippet:

```
const GaugeAnnotation(
              axisValue: 9.5,
              positionFactor: 0.9,
              widget: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 60.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.ads_click,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
```

Query 4: The needle pointer is not all in white.

By setting the color property to Colors.White in the KnobStyle, you can display the needle.

Code snippet:

```
pointers: const <GaugePointer>[
            NeedlePointer(
              value: 3,
              enableAnimation: true,
              animationType: AnimationType.linear,
              needleColor: Colors.white,
              needleStartWidth: 0.5,
              needleEndWidth: 5,
              knobStyle: KnobStyle(
                knobRadius: 0.04,
                sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                borderColor: Colors.white,
                borderWidth: 0.03,
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Screenshot:

[image]

We have shared a code snippet and user guide documentation for your reference. You can modify it based on your needs.

UG:
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/radial-gauge/needle-pointer#needle-customization
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/radial-gauge/needle-pointer#knob-customization
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/radial-gauge/annotation